# How to pass a python dictionary to div tag using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, dictionary

I have a div tag in and am fetching the data data from database in form of python dictionary using Ajax call. How can I pass this dictionary the div?
This is my Div tag

```
<div id="popup2" class="modal-box">
  <!-- some <tags> in this block -->
</div>
```

Here is My ajax response and I'm trying to assign python dictionary to div tag

```
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){

  if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4)
  {
    response = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    resdict = JSON.parse(response);
    $('popup2').text(resdict);
  }
}
```

I am unable to fetch the dictionary data in that particular div. Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Presumably ``resdict`` is a JSON object you're getting back and your Django view is returning the right thing. So to clarify your question you want to render ``resdict`` inside a ``<div>`` tag somehow? What is the structure of ``resdict`` and how should it be rendered?

Comment: it is python dictionary in the form of key and value pair, value has list of values i just want to iterate list in the div and generate some dynamic input fields there.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things I see and you may need to do.

First there's an error in your jQuery. Not sure if that's just in your question or your actual code.

```
$('popup2').text(resdict);  // wrong, does not find id
$('#popup2').text(resdict);  // correct, note the # hashtag
```

If that doesn't work make sure that you have a valid JSON object (no error) in your console. If you already have an error with `JSON.parse(response)` then check your response first.

```
console.log(response);
resdict = JSON.parse(response);
console.log(resdict);
```

Both log outputs should be valid code.

Comment: Thanks for your response i am successfully fetching the JSON object and i could print that using console.log();, but after converting it from JSON  to dictionary if i assign dictionary to div it is not happening....

Comment: And did you add the # so it's `$('#popup2')`